# Connection pooling and Thread.interrupt()

Tags: java, connection-pooling, c3p0, interrupt-handling, interrupted-exception

I am using [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) to handle database connection pooling in a multithreaded environment. The question might pertain to other pooling libs, but this is what I have.

Recently I've needed to implement [interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())ion handling on such threads using directly or indirectly c3p0, and have noticed that if `interrupt()` is called right when `c3p0Datasource.getConnection()` is trying to fetch me a `Connection` from the pool, it throws an `InterruptedException`.

Obviously, this happens because of the `wait()`

```
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1414)
```

Cool. The question is how do you handle this properly - both is case a) you want to continue with the transaction before your thread terminates, and b) you want to abort.

I've tried a solution that seems to be working fine (posted as answer) - actually, I think this subject is closed. Feel free to chip in otherwise, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a simple test by firing a lot of `Connection` requests within 1 second, executing a SELECT each time tim make sure the pool bottlenecks, and then calling `interrupt()`.

What I found was that the `connection` object is fine and dandy after the `InterruptedException` being caught, even though the stacktrace shows me c3p0 meltdown at `awaitAvailable(..)`. At this very second I'm checking out their sources, and surely, they handle the `InterruptedException`. They even throw a proper warning:

```
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5bcf4b61 -- an attempt to checkout a resource was interrupted, and the pool is still live: some other thread must have either interrupted the Thread attempting checkout!
```

telling us it's still live, albeit inbetween a lot of word fuzz. Solved.

Here's the test anyway.

```
ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();

// testing with various pool sizes - same effect
ds.setMinPoolSize(1);
ds.setMaxPoolSize(5);
ds.setInitialPoolSize(2);

Thread connectingThread = new Thread() {

    public void run() {
        Connection cnxn = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                cnxn = ds.getConnection();
                System.out.println("Got connection.");
                executeQuery(cnxn);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Got exception.");
                e.printStackTrace();

                // SOLUTION:
                Throwable cause = e.getCause();
                if (cause instanceof InterruptedException) {
                    System.out.println("Caught InterruptedException! Cnxn is " + cnxn);

                    // note that cnxn is a com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection
                    // also note that it's perfectly healthy.
                    //
                    // You may either want to:
                    // a) use the cnxn to submit your the query

                    executeQuery(cnxn);
                    cnxn.close()

                    // b) handle a proper shutdown

                    cnxn.close();

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };
};

connectingThread.start();
    
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {          e.printStackTrace();        }
    
connectingThread.interrupt();
```